# How do I run a script to start services during docker build phase?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a script I want to run that starts my hadoop services. I want to have this started during the build phase so that when I run the container those services are already running. I've tried adding CMD /script.sh but the services does not persist when I run my container. I also need bash to be running when I run my container.

Comment: can you show you Dockerfile?

Comment: Theres some business related stuff in there I cannot show. What did you want to see specifically?

Comment: you say " I want to have this started during the build phase so that when I run the container those services are already running" I doubt this is possible, the active(s) process in a container is what is launched by CMD/ENTRYPOINT, all the `RUN` in the Dockerfile is setting up your environment, if you do `RUN cd /tmp` and then `RUN ls` the ls will not be `ls /tmp`

Comment: I tried using CMD script.sh but the services do not persist when I start the container. Do you have any ideas why? From the official documentation it says that should work.

Comment: Have a look at `docker logs yourcontainer` and at `docker events`